# orange3-associate install fails, other add-ons install without issue

Tags: orange

Install error for Orang3-Associate add-on on a Windows7 PC

Command:

```
pip install Orange3-Associate  (same result from UI Options - Add-Ons)
```

Error:

```
Collecting Orange3-Associate
  Using cached Orange3-Associate-0.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-build-nzb1zehp\Orange3-Associate\setup.py", line                                               32, in <module>
        long_description=open(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'README.md')).re                                              ad(),
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\                                              pip-build-nzb1zehp\\Orange3-Associate\\README.md'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\cygwin64\tmp\p                                              ip-build-nzb1zehp\Orange3-Associate
```

Add-ons DataFusion and Text successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This was a bug in Orange3-Associate 0.1.1. It is hopefully fixed in 0.1.2, already available through `pip` or *Options | Add-ons*.

Comment: I downloaded and  installed the new build of Orange3 with version 0.1.2.    Different error code than before,  error code 1   (error noted:     error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).)

Comment: @StacyAjouri Yes, I believe you need a C/C++ compiler. If you don't wish to switch platforms (you'll never be able to do any advanced work on Windos), you can hopefully get a C++ compiler by installing [Vistual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) (claim unverified).

Comment: @StacyAjouri Please try version 0.1.3. The requirement for a compiler has been relaxed in favor of, as is always the case, worse performance on Windos systems. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Once I get a bit more familiar I will work on getting this installed on Linux.